# how to make phonegap build of sencha app to run on blackberry device

Tags: sencha-touch, blackberry-webworks

I develop a sencha touch application. Its working fine.
Now i want to deploy/ run this application on blackberry simulator.
i found many question related to this but i did not get what to do exactly.
Please someone help me how to do this?
How to make phonegap build of sencha application to run on blackberry simulator.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Please help me its very important for me.

Comment: In blackberry webwork project where i put model , view , controller files of sencha touch application?

Comment: Please anyone tell how to put sencha touch application file in to the blackberry webwork project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow phonegap's instructions for setting up a blackberry environment.

Build your project and move the entire contents of the built directory into the same folder that phonegap normally puts its index.html.

Follow phonegap's blackberry build instructions.

Comment: thanks kkl, For build i used command sencha app buila native and sencha app build package and putted all files in the www folder in blackberry project . but images name was the problem then i rename all the images and then i run the project but i get white screen (both on device and simulator). Can you please tell me what i'm doing in wrong way.

Comment: hi kkl, Can you describe prodecure in detail.

Comment: @ Alon Amir  But its given on sencha website its spporting blackberry os6 and above.